# How to fetch long datatype column value in TO_CLOB?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL query where am trying to fetch long datatype column value as mentioned below.

Here `NOTEACT.NOTE` is long datatype column and `TO_CLOB` method is used to generate EMAIL BODY.

> Error which am getting after running the query: ORA-00932:
> inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR  got LONG

Query part:

```sql
TO_CLOB(
        '<p style="color:black">'

        Please find notes from the activity <br><br> '|| NOTEACT.NOTE ||'

        Sincerely,

        <br><br>       

        '    || ASSIGN_TO.FST_NAME || ' ' || ASSIGN_TO.LAST_NAME || '

        </p>'

) AS "EMAIL_BODY"
```

Please let me know how I can fetch `NOTE` column value as part of above query.

Comment: `LONG` columns were deprecated from Oracle 8 you should use a `CLOB` column and can convert it using `ALTER TABLE noteact MODIFY ( note CLOB );`

Comment: Is there any option without altering datatype of column?